# custom 301 redirects from old joomla (mambo) website to new drupal 7 website using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, drupal-7

The past couple of hours I am trying to create custom redirects from an old mambo website to new drupal 7 website with the .htaccess file that exists in my drupal's root.
What I want to do is...

301 Redirect

http://mysite.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=blogsection&id=11&Itemid=54

to

http://mysite.com/this-is-the-new-page

This is my .htaccess file...

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index.php?option=com_content&task=blogsection&id=11&Itemid=54$ http://mysite.com/this-is-the-new-page [R=301,L]

RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I am sure that it has something to do with this line...

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

But I don't get it!
You see if I use this...

```
RewriteRule ^option=com_content&task=blogsection&id=11&Itemid=54$ http://mysite.com/this-is-the-new-page [R=301,L]
```

instead of this...

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?option=com_content&task=blogsection&id=11&Itemid=54$ http://mysite.com/this-is-the-new-page [R=301,L]
```

and test it with firefox and LiveHTTP Headers addon it works!

Any suggestions?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query string is not part of the [URL path pattern](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule). If you want to base a rule on the query string, you must do so in a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_content&task=blogsection&id=11&Itemid=54
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /this-is-the-new-page? [R,L]
```

Comment: thank you for your reply! It does the redirection but it appends at the end the QUERY_STRING. So now I have http://mysite.com/this-is-the-new-page?option=com_content&task=blogsection&id=11&Itemid=54 :(

Comment: @kanenas.net Sorry, I always forget to add a question mark `?` at the end of the substitution. Fixed.