# Disallow access to certain page from blank or "-" referrer with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having some trouble with DDOS attacks lately again.
Basically I want to disallow access to a certain path.

Example from log file:

> 109.242.25.254 - - [23/Mar/2013:16:09:35 +0100] "GET /?op=my_account HTTP/1.1" 200 4218 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US;
>   rv:1.9.0.10) Gecko/2009042523 Ubuntu/9.04 (jaunty) Firefox/3.0.10

So I want to disallow access from blank referrers or "-" referrers to the path "?op=my_account" and just send them to a 403 page.

I started this like this with htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www.)?mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^\?op=my_account$ - [F]
```

so basically I disallow all other referers to this page except my page.
but somehow this wont work.
I think I am missing something in the second line?

Comment: The query string is not part of the url path, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15534702/1741542

Comment: sorry, but I don't know exactly where you are refering to? which url path?!

Comment: The pattern (first part) in the `RewriteRule` does not include the query string `?op=my_account`. You must use a `RewriteCond` instead.

Comment: ich kapiers nicht.... i am using the RewriteRule to define the referer and the cond to send them an 403 with [F] if my_account is accessed. this works fine with avoiding hotlinking of images e.g.

Comment: Which means "I don't understand it" for non-german speaking fellows ;-) You have a `RewriteRule \?op=my_account ...`, which includes a query string. If you want to test for the query string `op=my_account`, you cannot use it in `RewriteRule`, but must use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ...` as outlined in the answer, I linked in my comment above.

Comment: I give up, thanks for your help anyway

Comment: I want to avoid duplicate answers, this is why I link to earlier answers, if they are similar. Anyway, look at my answer, this should solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `\?op=my_account` in [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), because the query string is not available there, only the URL path. You must use [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) with a `%{QUERY_STRING}` instead

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^op=my_account$
RewriteRule ^$ - [F]
```

Comment: ok, I see now what you mean, I did not know about the QUERY_STRING command. I just read about it on another page, sorry. allthough still it is not working :-S